# iOS9 screenshot does not show TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using following code to capture screenshot of whole screen, including statusbar and **TabBar**:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);    
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];

UIImage *imageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageNew, nil, nil, nil);
```

It draws everything except statusbar and **TabBar**

Comment: I don't know what "self" is exactly here, but I highly doubt that it contains the status bar or the tab bar. It probably is just a view controller and hence self.view is the view itself.

Comment: `self.view` refers to the main view, doesn't it?

Comment: It refers to the view of "self", whatever that is. Only you know. But it most probably is not the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
CALayer *layer = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].layer;
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, scale);

[layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
```

I had test it in my application and it takes the screenshot of **Tabbar**.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: No, I have several dynamically created layers which won't be shown if I sue this method.

Answer (score 0):

Only after every UI components are settled on `viewDidAppear`, call screen shot capturing code block.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

//Screen capturing code goes here...

}
```

Comment: But I don't want to capture on `viewDidAppear()`!

Comment: Ok, then we have to find the place where every UI elements are visible in controller.